# Symfony2 : Unit testing with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I'm using phpunit with Symfony2.

I decided to use sqlite for my tests.

The issue I'm having is that the foreign keys constraints are ignored.

I know I have to execute the following query in order to use foreign keys : `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`).

My question is : is there a way to always use foreign keys when creating the database schema with sqlite ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is impossible. Accordingly to [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled,
>   it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the
>   PRAGMA foreign_keys command.

I would suggest to create your own test case class and use setUp() method to enable foreign keys.

```
class SQLiteTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    parent::setUp();
    // Here add your code to enable foreign keys
  }
}

class MyTest extends SQLiteTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    // Setup your test data-set here
    parent::setUp();
  }
}
```